# How to replace the Action Bar app title with a TextView?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've removed the app title from my Action Bar using

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

in my onCreate.

I'd like help with two things:

1. How would I remove the app title through XML, so my preview wouldn't still show it?
2. How would I place an EditText (Mine is R.id.urlField) in my Action Bar in place of the app title, where a URL field of an internet browser should be?

Sample code and examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom View for the ActionBar like this:

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
```

You can then find Views from the custom View in the ActionBar like this:

```
View actionBarView = getActionBar().getCustomView(); 

EditText editText = (EditText) acitonBarView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Or you can just directly set a View instance as custom View like this:

```
 EditText editText = new EditText(context);
 getActionBar().setCustomView(editText);
```

And take a look --> [Here](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-add-custom-view-actionbar/)

Comment: Use the SupportActionbar  > android.support.v7.app.ActionBar  actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); @Adam

Comment: Your resource that you linked ended up working for me once I created a custom view and put my EditText xml in that. Thank you very much!